# Filtering JSON Data based on a time frame to return data that falls between weekly interval

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a set of JSON data where `Date()` as one of the parameters, I want to filter this data to return only the JSON data that falls between a week and two weeks.

I have a function that convert my date to days, so I was passing this function into filtering of my data.

**Date conversion function:**

```js
const dateConverter = (startDate, timeEnd) => {
    const newStartDate = new Date(startDate);
    const newEndDate = new Date(timeEnd);
    const one_day = 1000*60*60*24;
    let result;
    result = Math.ceil((newEndDate.getTime() - newStartDate.getTime()) / (one_day));
    console.log('date Converter result', result);
    if (result < 0) { return 0; }
    return result;
  }
```

Here is where I am checking for a valid time frame against my filter:

```js
const above_10 = Defaultdata.filter((d, i) => {
    return(d.delivery_time_frame.length > 10);
});
```

I am filtering the actual data with the function above though I am not getting the expected result:

```js
const next_level = above_10.filter((d, i)=>{
    return(
      // d.delivery_time_frame.split('-')[0] = "2021-10-25"
      dateConverter(`${ d.delivery_time_frame.split('-')[0] }`, `${ d.delivery_time_frame.split('-')[0] }`)
    )
})
```

What my Default data look like

```
const Defaultdata = [{date_listed: "4 hours ago",
id: "7857699961",
delivery_time_frame: "2021-10-25 - 2021-11-14",
distance: "22.8 km",
time_stamp: "2021-10-25 16:36:54",
watched: "yes",
} , {
    
date_listed: "3 days ago",
id: "8358962006",
delivery_time_frame: "2021-10-18 - 2021-10-24",
distance: "4.3 km",

time_stamp: "2021-10-22 16:54:12",

}, {
    date_listed: "4 hours ago",
delivery_id: "8146462294",
delivery_time_frame: "2021-10-25",
distance: "4.3 km",
time_stamp: "2021-10-25 16:12:32",

} ]

Basically, what I want to archive from this is to return the data that falls within a week and two weeks based on the timeframe in the data.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `"2021-10-25 - 2021-11-14` is your input,

`d.delivery_time_frame.split('-')[0]` is "2021" for all dates, so
both `new Date(startDate)` and `new Date(timeEnd)` evaluate to 2021-01-01...
you have to parse your dates differently, for example you can use fixed  length substrings:

```
dateConverter(`${ d.delivery_time_frame.substr(0,10) }`, `${ d.delivery_time_frame.substr(13,10) }`) > 10
```

EDIT

a probably more elegant and more robust solution would be to use a regular expression to parse for your dates:

```
let dates = d.delivery_time_frame.match(/(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)/g)
dateConverter(`${ dates[0] }`, `${ dates[1] }`) > 10
```

Comment: Yes, I guess it was a mistake from my end  @HolgerWill . Still, I'm still not getting the expected result after correcting that. I have added my Defaultdata to the question as well

Comment: ok, i see. thanks. i changed my answer to give a real solution... hth